# Problema al obtener redes LAN con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

Hola comunidad de programadores,

Tengo un problema al intentar obtener las IPs conectadas a una red LAN, al momento de recibir   las direcciones ip, me arroja un valor nulo. Estoy usando python3.7.

El problema especificamente creo se encuentra dentro de la funcion map_network, lo extraño es que me funcionaba en linux, pero al transcribir a Windows dejo de obtener las direcciones ip.

Librerias:
socket
multiprocessing
subprocess
os
PrettyTable
getmac

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(getDataTable())

    exit()
```

```
def getDataTable():
    counter = 1
    lst = map_network()
    dt = PrettyTable()
    dt.field_names = ["ID","IP","MAC Address"]

    for i in range(len(lst)):

        mac = get_mac_address(ip=lst[i])

        dt.add_row([counter,lst[i],mac])

        counter += 1
    return dt
```

```
def map_network(pool_size=255):
    ip_list = list()

    # get my IP and compose a base like 192.168.1.xxx
    ip_parts = get_my_ip().split('.')
    base_ip = ip_parts[0] + '.' + ip_parts[1] + '.' + ip_parts[2] + '.'

    # prepare the jobs queue
    jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    pool = [multiprocessing.Process(target=pinger, args=(jobs, results)) for i in range(pool_size)]

    for p in pool:
        p.start()

    # cue hte ping processes
    for i in range(1, 255):
        jobs.put(base_ip + '{0}'.format(i))

    for p in pool:
        jobs.put(None)

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    # Collect IPs result
    while not results.empty():
        ip = results.get()
        ip_list.append(ip)
    if results.empty():
        ip = "None"
        ip_list.append(ip)
    return ip_list
```

```
def get_my_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    return ip
```

Comment: en pool, que es pinger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, yo tengo un script que hice una vez para sistemas Windows, es un poco diferente al tuyo pero funciona muy bien, aparte que es multihilo. Te lo comparto:

```
import os
import sys
import platform
import threading, subprocess
from datetime import datetime

IPXHILOS = 4
ip = input("Ingresa la IP: ")
ipDividida = ip.split('.')

try:
    red = ipDividida[0]+'.'+ipDividida[1]+'.'+ipDividida[2]+'.'
    comienzo = int(input("Ingresa el número de comienzo de la subred: "))
    fin = int(input("Ingresa el número en el que deseas acabar el barrido: "))
except:
    print("[!] Error")
    sys.exit(1)


if (platform.system()=="Windows"):
    ping = "ping -n 1"
else :
    ping = "ping -c 1"
    

class Hilo (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,inicio,fin):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.inicio = inicio
        self.fin = fin
        
    def run(self):
        for subred in range(self.inicio,self.fin):
            direccion = red+str(subred)
            response = os.popen(ping+" "+direccion)
            for line in response.readlines():
                if ("ttl" in line.lower()):
                    print(direccion,"está activo")
                    break


tiempoInicio = datetime.now()
print("[*] El escaneo se está realizando desde",red+str(comienzo),"hasta",red+str(fin))
NumeroIPs = fin-comienzo
numeroHilos = int((NumeroIPs/IPXHILOS))
hilos = []

try:
    for i in range(numeroHilos):
        finAux = comienzo+IPXHILOS
        if(finAux > fin):
            finAux = fin
        hilo = Hilo(comienzo, finAux)
        hilo.start()
        hilos.append(hilo)
        comienzo = finAux
except Exception as e:
    print("[!] Error creando hilos:",e)
    sys.exit(2)


for hilo in hilos:
    hilo.join()

tiempoFinal = datetime.now()
tiempo = tiempoFinal - tiempoInicio
print("[*] El escaneo ha durado %s"%tiempo)
```

Éxitos y buena suerte!

Comment: Era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias Amilcar :)